# Is there a way to show picture if html has been included in another file

Tags: html, asp-classic, include

Problem: I have a file called `index.html`. this file has been included in another file called `main.asp`.

```
<!--#include virtual="/template/index.html"-->
```

`index.html` has a image tag `<img src="abcd.jpg"/>` image is in the same directory where `index.html` resides. ...  When this method is being used it is not possible to display the images in `index.html` which has been included in main.asp.

Answer (score 1):

Use an absolute path in the image `src`:

```
<img src="/template/abcd.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser will try to locate assets based on the relative position of the current document.

So you will need to reference the image from the location of `main.asp` in your file structure, not `index.html`

Comment: Great! I thought you should know the theory behind referencing assets and including files.